# What to write in HAR when request does not have an answer?

Tags: python, har

I have a situation where I get Chrome's performance logs after running some automated tests. Then I parse it with a script I made to get a HAR file (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/).
Everything runs works correctly most of the times, but every now and then I get a request that has no answer (whether I stopped the page loading before it gets complete, or something else). I tried leaving the "response" object blank for this request, but this is required. After that, I tried removing the object, but it is required too.
What should I do in those cases? Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some debug i found out that requests that have no answer do not go to HAR. At least that is what WebPageTest does and what I did.